# Unable to Edit TaskSubtype Picklist Values

Tags: picklist, tasks

I'm unable to add any picklist values to the Task field TaskSubtype. I actually can't even see the current values without looping through the describe results for TaskSubtype.

I have no problem accessing or querying the field, I've confirmed that I have customize application checked for my profile, the field is visible and editable to my profile, and it's listed as a field whose available picklist values are controlled by the record type. I saw in the Salesforce documentation that TaskSubtype is not a changeable field, but as far as I understand it just means the field is immutable. Am I wrong in that understanding, or am I just missing something else? Or is this just something you can't do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TaskSubtype` has a number of special behaviors. It dictates how Activities are displayed on the Lightning Activity timeline, in particular.

You cannot add picklist values to the field, and you also cannot update its values on existing records (although you can populate the field in a `before insert` trigger, or when creating records via the API or Data Loader).

Basically, like a few things about Tasks and Events, it's magic.

Comment: That's incredibly frustrating. I'm sure there's some good reason they have it that way, but frustrating nonetheless. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm definitely with you on that. Give this Idea an upvote if you wish; it's related but not quite the same: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000COq5QAG

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar situation where I needed to append a few options to the 'Task subtype'. Eventually, I identified the solution. Navigate to the 'Activity' object (Setup > Object Manager) and reference the 'Sub Types' field to make the necessary updates. Thanks.